# BSOD when I turn on a virtual machine but I do not have Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, bsod

I have a problem because when I try to launch Nox, Bluestack, MuMu, or any other emulator, I receive a BSOD with a SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION.

I have read that I have to uninstall Hyper-V as a windows component. I have it uninstalled. The only thing that I have is the new Unix virtual machine system activated. I have the same problem on my PC and my laptop. Both with Windows 10 updated, Nvidia graphic card, Intel, ... and all updated.

This problem occurs in both of my PC. I have a MSI Laptop GE60 2Qe Apache Pro with Nvidia GTX960M, Intel Core i7. My PC is an Intel Core i7 4770, Zotac Nvidia 670 GTX, and an Asus Z87-Deluxe Mainboard. Both PC has windows 10 updated.

Some idea about how to solve this problem?

Here I attached a screenshot of BlueScreenView:
[image: BlueScreenView screenshot]
[image]

This is my Bios:

[image]

Comment: Please install [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) and add to your post the screenshots of both viewing modes.

Comment: I have attached the screen. Is that or you need another view? I do not know this programme. Thx.

Comment: Use the View menu to also add [this view](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluescreenview.gif).

Comment: That is already is in my screenshot, isn't it?

Comment: No, add the one that duplicates the BSOD screen.

Comment: Is that screenshot?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately is doesn't help to analyze the problem. I'll wait for your response to user veritaS.

Comment: The screenshot isn't helpful.  It doesn't show that VT-x is enabled.  It shows us nothing that can help us answer your quesiton.

Comment: "I have read that I have to uninstall Hyper-V as a windows component. I have it uninstalled. The only thing that I have is the new Unix virtual machine system activated. " - **Which means you have Hyper-V enabled. **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The only thing that I have is the new Unix virtual machine system activated.

Assuming you mean WSL2, note that that runs on top of the Hyper-V hypervisor, which may appear as "Virtual Machine Platform". That will conflict with other hardware virtualisation consumers in the same way full Hyper-V would.

Of course, if you disable that you may not be able to use WSL2.

See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, that your CPU virtualisation setting is interfearing with this VM I had the same with docker and vagrant and hyper-v, having to switch off and on this setting each time I want the other solution to start up. This is a setting in your bios.

First,
Turn off Hyper-V [here](https://www.isumsoft.com/it/how-to-enable-or-disable-hyper-v-in-windows-10/)

or powershell
enable

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V –All
```

disable

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
```

Now restart PC and then Turn off virtualisation in your BIOS by following [this](https://www.isunshare.com/blog/how-to-enable-virtualizationvt-in-bios-for-hyper-v-windows-10/) guide and check if that fixes your issue.

EDIT: Here is a picture and [this](https://www.msi.com/support/technical_details/MB_BIOS_Manual) link to your bios manual

[image]

Comment: I had done those steps but I did not obtain anything. The problem continues.

Comment: Including turning off virtualisation in your bios?

Comment: In my MSI Laptop I do not have those options :S I searched any another similar but I found nothing.

Comment: in both PC´s? What is your mainboard / CPU ? OR laptop id/name

Comment: I have edited my post with that information.

Comment: I added a screenshot and a link to your bios manual

Comment: I did not have that programme. I have installed it but that programme does not support my mainboard :S

Comment: can you add a screenshot/photo of ur bios and or its version to your post?

Comment: I have attached that photo.